# excluding grouping to run a statistical test in tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, statistics, tidyverse

I was wondering why my `mshapiro_test()` call below throws an error?

I want this call to exclude variables `ID` and `Group` in my data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)

d <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/memory.csv")

d %>% group_by(Group) %>% select(-ID) %>%  mshapiro_test()

#Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
#x is.numeric(x) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cur_data()` within `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   select(-ID) %>% 
   group_by(Group) %>% 
   summarise(out = list(mshapiro_test(cur_data())))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Group out             
#* <chr> <list>          
#1 CON   <tibble [1 × 2]>
#2 HI    <tibble [1 × 2]>
#3 MT    <tibble [1 × 2]>
```

The `out` is a `list` column.  It can be `unnest`ed

```
library(tidyr)
d %>%
    select(-ID) %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    summarise(out = list(mshapiro_test(cur_data()))) %>%
    unnest(c(out))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Group statistic p.value
#  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 CON       0.907   0.122
#2 HI        0.963   0.599
#3 MT        0.947   0.412
```

---

The `cur_data()` only selects the columns that are not the grouping

```
d %>% 
  select(-ID) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(out = list(head(cur_data(), 2))) %>%
  pull(out)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     MP    SE
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     6
2     6     4

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     MP    SE
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    10     7
2     7     8

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     MP    SE
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     9
2     7     9
```

---

Or another option is `group_split` with `map`

```
library(purrr)
d %>% 
    select(-ID) %>% 
    group_split(Group, .keep = FALSE) %>% 
    map_dfr(mshapiro_test)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  statistic p.value
#      <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     0.907   0.122
#2     0.963   0.599
#3     0.947   0.412
```

---

Or using `base R` with `split` and `sapply/lapply`

```
sapply(split(d[3:4], d$Group), mshapiro_test)
#           CON       HI        MT       
#statistic 0.9070134 0.9627111 0.9470829
#p.value   0.1218592 0.5993172 0.4120478
```

Comment: @rnorouzian it is just that the output from `mshapiro_test` is a not a single column.  So, have to wrap it in a `list`

Comment: Now the answer is correct with group split.

Comment: @rnorouzian because you are passing a string vector and not the column of the dataset you may need `with(d, sapply(split(d[c("MP","SE")], Group), mshapiro_test))` `split` using `with` can get the value of the column if it is unquoted..  With multiple columns, you may need to `cbind` or `data.frame`

Comment: @rnorouzian you can `t`ranspose and convert the column to rownames with `column_to_rownames`